# First MacBook - am stuck

Tags: macbook-pro

I've unboxed a MacBook Pro and am stuck at the very beginning. These are the two screens that loop - I have no idea what I'm supposed to be doing now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's telling you to turn on your bluetooth mouse and CD/DVD player.

Comment: Thanks - but I don't have any of them

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192464/88313).  It's similar but not a duplicate.  The answers might help.

Comment: Do you have access to a wired USB mouse and keyboard? They don't even have to be Apple branded.

Comment: Hi. thanks guys. I went back to the store and they replaced the laptop.

Comment: @fsb that last one is a keyboard, not cd player.

Comment: A keyboard?  Wow, I wouldn't have guessed that, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple offers free support at 1-888-APL-CARE for all new hardware. But, you seem to be seeing the screens that guide you to use a wireless keyboard and a wireless mouse.

What happens if you disconnect everything connected to the Mac and then open the lid of the MacBook Pro and type?

If you can't get logged in, a quick call to support might be the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just visited the Apple Store for the exact same issue with the same images.

They saw the images and told that the trackpad is dead and I should contact the online shop that I bought the Macbook from.