# Can not login to MacBook Pro... strange boot screen

Tags: macbook-pro

Problem: My 2015 retina MacBook Pro is currently stuck booting up to this screen. It happened after I tried following some troubleshooting tips as my MacBook started to freeze up. I’m afraid I made it worst. This occurred after trying SMC reset and I can’t get back any other screen.

It seems to be asking me to turn it off with a switch? But I don’t have a switch on the side of my Mac. Is there a way to fix this before I take it to get checked out at the store? ;(

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This means your keyboard and mouse are *not* being recognized by the operating system. Try plugging in an external USB mouse/keyboard to do some troubleshooting.

You could also try resetting SMC/NVRAM again.

See 
[MacBook Air boots to strange screen showing Magic Mouse and TrackPad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192448/macbook-air-boots-to-strange-screen-showing-magic-mouse-and-trackpad)