# Mac Mini does not boot, shows only strange symbols instead

Tags: startup, mac-mini

My Mac mini does no longer boot and only shows two strange symbols instead:

[image]

[image]

What is wrong and how can I recover the system?

BTW: Why does apple use strange symbols that can't be understood instead of just printing a reasonable error message even the stupidest person could simply enter in a search engine and directly get to an answer what is wrong?

Comment: I don't have a mouse connected, the system is usually running headless (access via VNC/ssh),  it has just a keyboard connected for entering the disc encryption password. This was working well for quite some time.

Comment: You must connect both a mouse and a keyboard to boot it.

Comment: @nohillside This sounds like stupid Apple logic, you don't need a mouse but you have to connect one to boot up the system. Also this Mac was running fine with Catalina and Big Sur 11.4 without a mouse.

Comment: @JMax This is a community of people trying to help. There is no point in being rude and calling things stupid. If you have feedback for Apple, place it at https://www.apple.com/feedback/ 
 ; Pro tip for both IT and life: It's a lot more likely for people to care about your feedback or helping you when you're polite.

Comment: Do you mind if I soften the “stupid” commented here and deltete this comment afterwards JMax - I get being frustrated but I think people may see this as a hothead  gripe and not a legit complaint about an engineering decision.

Comment: @bmike Sorry but I don't see why you have a problem with my last comment. The "stupid" was not directed to a user and that the way Apple tries to tell us "please connect a pointing device like a mouse or touchpad" is not what I could call "user friendly" or "intelligent" (or do you disagree?). So why not name it as it is? BTW: I now understand that the second picture seems to show the bottom of a magic mouse. But what is the first image showing - a MacBook with closed lid?

Comment: I’ll take that as you you mind I remove the name calling in the abstract. The graphics depict a Magic Trackpad and a Magic Mouse

Answer (score 4):

These prompts are meant to get you to connect the mouse or trackpad that ships with Apple hardware and I presume they chose pictures of the Bluetooth gear since they wanted this to work before the language localization is established. This can also get displayed when there is a firmware or major system/security update. In rare cases, you cannot use screen sharing to bypass this - a physical pointing device is required unless you have MDM supervisory control over the device.

If you [connect any USB keyboard and Mouse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370508/5472), you can proceed to set up your Mac.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-mini/welcome/mac

> After you connect a display, keyboard, and mouse or trackpad, press the power button on the back of your Mac mini. Follow the Setup Assistant prompts, and you’re up and running.

[Set up your Mac mini](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-mini/set-up-your-mac-apd831707cb3/2020/mac/11)

If for some reason you [have already connected a keyboard and mouse, there may be a hardware error](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192464/5472).